# Binary file modification using python

Tags: python, bin

Solution in comments.

I'm currently able to append a .bin file. My implementation is:

```
patch1 = b'\xde\xad\xbe\xef\xde\xad\xbe\xef\xde\xad\xbe\xef\xde\xad\xbe\xef\xDD'

with open('test.bin', 'r+b') as fh:
    # apply patch1
    fh.seek(0x00040000)
    fh.write(patch1)
```

The only way I can append 'test.bin' file is by placing the prefix '\x' to 'patch1'.
Is there a better way to modify my bytes in `patch1` bytes without using '\x' ?

I have tried to remove the \x entirely but this doesn't seem to work. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: `patch1 = bytes.fromhex('deadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdd')` https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.fromhex